# Designing non-real time, non-blocking, result-dependent system

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, architecture, system-design

**Context:**

1) We have a scheduler which picks up jobs and process them by calling another rest-call in a blocking manner.

2) Scheduler thread needs to wait for the rest-call to complete and in-turn do some another task based upon the result.

3) There is no constraint for this to be real time.

**Problem Statement:**

1) What we want is to free scheduler threads as soon as an external call is made as external call takes significant time to complete.

2) We should be informed about the result received from the external call as we need to do some processing based on the result.

**Idea in my mind:**

1) Rather than calling the external system using synchronous Http call, we 
   can push the event to the queue.

2) Api consumer of another system will read the event from the queue and do the long running task. And post processing push the result back to the queue on a different topic.

3) Our system now can read the response from the queue(second topic) and do the necessary actions.

This is one of the design approach that comes to my

I need advice on whether we can improve the design somehow.

1) Can this be done without introduction of queue ?

2) Is there any better way to achieve the asynchronous processing ?

Comment: I don't understand 'What we want is to free scheduler threads when an external call is made'. This the point at which you would *allocate* a thread, not free it.

Comment: We have a scheduler which picks up jobs and process them by calling another rest-call in a blocking manner. Since the call takes too much time, we need to make it non-blocking, but we do have to do some processing based on the result of the call. That we can do in non-real time basis

Comment: That doesn't answer my question in any way.

Comment: i edited the question. Is it fine now ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using a queue, I can think of 2 other alternatives, for example:

> 1) Rather than calling the external system using synchronous Http call, we can push the event to the queue.

alternative a)

you  do a synchronous HTTP GET to tell the other system that you want certain job to be executed (the other system replies quickly with a "200 OK" to confirm that it received the request).

alternative b)

you do a synchronous HTTP GET to tell the other system that you want certain job to be executed (the other system replies quickly with a "200 OK" and a unique ID to identify the job to be executed)

> 2) Api consumer of another system will read the event from the queue and do the long running task. And post processing push the result back to the queue on a different topic.
>   3) Our system now can read the response from the queue(second topic) and do the necessary actions.

alternative a)

upon receiving the request, the other system performs the long running computation and then when it is ready it makes a synchronous HTTP call to your original system to inform that the job is ready.

alternative b)

upon receiving the request, the other system performs the long running computation. 
the original system doesn't know if the job is done, so it polls at certain times (doing a synchronous HTTP GET to a different REST API) providing the JOB ID, to find out if the job is ready.

Comment: It is not like i want to avoid usage of queue. I want to do the job at hand with the best possible design, using extra resources only if required (considering cost as well in mind.)

Comment: I understand. adding a messaging queue increases costs and also adds the problem of making sure that the queue is running at all times. it also adds more complexity to the system. But on the other hand, if you want resilience,  a messaging queue is the best option. It decouples the client/server and when the messaging queue is deployed in high availability configuration it provides a guarantee that no message will be lost.

Comment: in summary: to coordinate work between two systems, it is not possible to make a general assumption that a system that uses a messaging queue is better or worse than one without it. (it depends on your requirements, budget and time available to implement the solution)

Comment: Lets remove cost here ... I need to build a scalable and fault-tolerant system. Then how would you go about it ?

Comment: A messaging queue (RabbitMQ or Kafka) deployed in high availability configuration.

Comment: So given the context here you find Queue based approach best.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147726/discussion-between-sahil-gupta-and-jose-zevallos).